# Spoofing Firefox 4 User Agent without add-ons

Tags: firefox, user-agent

Is there a way to spoof UA without installation of an add-on? They have broken `general.useragent.extra.firefox` in version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `general.useragent.override`.